# Intersection of minimal topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am working on some problems in toric arrangements theory, particularly in the proof that the integer cohomology of the complement manifold of these arrangements is torsion-free.

First, let us recall some basic definitions. A topological space $X$ is said to be minimal if it has the homotopy type of a CW-complex with exactly $b_{m}$ cells, where $b_{m}=\operatorname{rk}H^{m}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is the m-th Betti number of $X$ as $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

A direct consequence of the minimality of a topological space $X$ is that its integer cohomology is torsion-free.

Here is the **question**. Let $U$ and $V$ be minimal topological spaces and let $X=U\cap V$ be the intersection of such spaces. Under which condition the topological space $X$ is minimal, too?

Thanks you very much for your kindful help.

Comment: What is an intersection of two topological spaces?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "cell decomposition admits CW-complexes"?

Answer (score 2):

Intersection is not a homotopy-theoretic operation, and the homotopy type of two subspaces $X, Y$ of some ambient space does not control the homotopy type of $X \cap Y$ whatsoever. Indeed, let $Z$ be an arbitrary topological space and consider its (unreduced) [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)); formally, consider $Z \times [0, 1]$ and then identify together all points of the form $(z, 0)$, then all points of the form $(z, 1)$. Let

$$X = \left\{ (z, t) : t \le \frac{1}{2} \right\}$$
$$Y = \left\{ (z, t) : t \ge \frac{1}{2} \right\}.$$

Then $X, Y$ are two [cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) over $Z$ and so are contractible, hence minimal (since they have the homotopy type of a point). But their intersection $X \cap Y$ is homeomorphic to $Z$ and so has arbitrary homotopy type. The homotopy type of $X$ and $Y$ can really be arbitrary here, you just attach an arbitrary topological space to each cone point.

Comment: Your “double cone” is just the **un**reduced suspension, isn’t it?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.